# Winlogbeat Message field missing

Tags: windows, apache-kafka, elastic-stack, event-log, filebeat

Using Winlogbeats for forwarding messages from Windows host to a Kafka Cluster.
Installed winlog beats agent on the host and trying to forward the Security logs to the Kafka broker. But I see the message field is missing from the Events.
Winlogbeat config:

```
#======================= Winlogbeat specific options ==========================
winlogbeat.event_logs:
- name: Security
ignore_older: 72h
forwarded: true
fields:
  log_topic: TEST
  extra_id: testId
fields_under_root: true
#------------------------------- Kafka output ----------------------------------
output.kafka:
# Boolean flag to enable or disable the output module.
 enabled: true
# The list of Kafka broker addresses from where to fetch the cluster metadata.
# The cluster metadata contain the actual Kafka brokers events are published
# to.
output.kafka.hosts: ["localhost:9092","localhost:9093"]
output.kafka.topic: '%{[log_topic]}'
```

I was able to run the Winlogbeat and see traffic going to Kafka, but the issue is that the message field is missing from the below-redacted output record.

```
 "record_number": "20092012",
  "event_data": {
    "TargetLogonId": "00000000",
    "LogonType": "3",
    "TargetUserName": "USER1",
    "TargetDomainName": "DOMAIN",
    "TargetUserSid": "1-1-1-1-1"
```

I am Expecting to see something like below sent by the Winlogbeat

```
*message: An account was logged off.
Subject:
    Security ID:        S-000000000000000000000
    Account Name:       000000
    Account Domain:     DOmain
    Logon ID:       0x1234
Logon Type:         7
This event is generated when a logon session is destroyed. It may be positively correlated with a logon event using the Logon ID value. Logon IDs are only unique between reboots on the same computer.*
```

Am I missing anything in the winlogbeat.yml config file?

Comment: So you're expecting to see the text `An account was logged off.` and `This event is generated when a logon session is destroyed. It may be positively correlated with a logon event using the Logon ID value. Logon IDs are only unique between reboots on the same computer.` included in what's sent from winlogbeat? Or something else?

Comment: That's Correct.